# Why aren't any of my view components appearing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to complete the assignment of making the screen a rainbow color. I inserted view components and inserted the stylesheet, but nothing is showing up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                
                <View style={styles.violet}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.indigo}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.blue}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.green}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.yellow}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.orange}>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.red}>
                </View>
            
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
    },
    violet: {
        height: 58,
        backgroundColor: '#94OOD3',
    },
    indigo: {
        backgroundColor: '#4BOO82',
        height: 58,
    },
    blue: {
        backgroundColor: '#OOOOFF',
        height: 58,
    },
    green: {
        backgroundColor: '#OOFFOO',
        height: 58,
    },
    yellow: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFOO',
        height: 58,
    },
    orange: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF7FOO',
        height: 58,
    },
    red: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFOOOO',
        height: 58,
    }
});
```

I have been trying to fix this for quite some time; if any of you could please point out an issue, I would much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the wrong syntax for colors. Change all O with 0 (zero).

```
violet: {
    height: 58,
    backgroundColor: "#9400D3"
  },
  indigo: {
    backgroundColor: "#4B0082",
    height: 58
  },
  blue: {
    backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
    height: 58
  },
  green: {
    backgroundColor: "#00FF00",
    height: 58
  },
  yellow: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFF00",
    height: 58
  },
  orange: {
    backgroundColor: "#FF7F00",
    height: 58
  },
  red: {
    backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
    height: 58
  }
```

Comment: Thank  you very much.